# Is there any difference between Link-local and Site-local scope in IPv6 world?

Tags: ipv6

What is the difference between Node-Local-Scope, Site-Local-Scope and Link-Local-Scope ?

What does it mean Link local (link only) ? Is it only for a Subnet ? 
Why do we need site-local address then ?

Thanks in Advance
Sajith

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For unicast IPv6, you don't have scopes the way you have in your question. There are Reserved unicast addresses, Global unicast addresses (`2000::/3`'), Unique-Local unicast addresses (`fc00::/7`, with restrictions), and Link-Local unicast addresses (`fe80::/10`).

IPv6 Link-Local unicast has identifiers to uniquely identify the interface in a host that are often called the scope (or zone) identifier. This is necessary because all the interfaces will use the same network. See the [*IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml). The IPv6 unicast Link-Local addressing is only valid on the link because every link has the same network, and you cannot route or send traffic from one link to another using Link-Local addresses.

IPv6 multicast that has:

- Interface-Local scope
- Link-Local scope
- Realm-Local scope
- Admin-Local scope
- Site-Local scope
- Organization-Local scope
- Global scope

[*RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Section 2.7. Multicast Addresses*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.7) defines some of these:

> Interface-Local scope spans only a single interface on a node and is
> useful only for loopback transmission of multicast.
>
> Link-Local multicast scope spans the same topological region as the
> corresponding unicast scope.
>
> Admin-Local scope is the smallest scope that must be administratively
> configured, i.e., not automatically derived from physical connectivity
> or other, non-multicast-related configuration.
>
> Site-Local scope is intended to span a single site.
>
> Organization-Local scope is intended to span multiple sites belonging
> to a single organization.

[*RFC 7346, IPv6 Multicast Address Scopes*](http://IPv6%20Multicast%20Address%20Scopes) updates the IPv6 multicast scopes:

> 2. Definition of IPv6 Multicast Address Scopes (Updates RFC 4291)
>
> The following table updates the definitions in [RFC4291]:
>
> ```
>     +------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
>     | scop | NAME                     | REFERENCE               |
>     +------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
>     |  0   | Reserved                 | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  1   | Interface-Local scope    | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  2   | Link-Local scope         | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  3   | Realm-Local scope        | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  4   | Admin-Local scope        | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  5   | Site-Local scope         | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  6   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  7   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  8   | Organization-Local scope | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  9   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  A   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  B   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  C   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  D   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  E   | Global scope             | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  F   | Reserved                 | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     +------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
> ```
>
> The following change is applied to Section 2.7 of [RFC4291].
>
> OLD:
>
> Admin-Local scope is the smallest scope that must be administratively
> configured, i.e., not automatically derived from physical connectivity
> or other, non-multicast-related configuration.
>
> NEW:
>
> Interface-Local, Link-Local, and Realm-Local scope boundaries are
> automatically derived from physical connectivity or other non-
> multicast-related configurations.  Global scope has no boundary. The
> boundaries of all other non-reserved scopes of Admin-Local or larger
> are administratively configured.  For reserved scopes, the way of
> configuring their boundaries will be defined when the semantics of the
> scope are defined.
>
> According to RFC 4007 [RFC4007], the zone of a Realm-Local scope must
> fall within zones of larger scope.  Because the zone of a Realm-Local
> scope is configured automatically while the zones of larger scopes are
> configured manually, care must be taken in the definition of those
> larger scopes to ensure that the inclusion constraint is met.
>
> Realm-Local scopes created by different network technologies are
> considered to be independent and will have different zone indices (see
> Section 6 of [RFC4007]).  A router with interfaces on links using
> different network technologies does not forward traffic between the
> Realm-Local multicast scopes defined by those technologies.
>
> 3. Definition of Realm-Local Scopes
>
> The definition of any Realm-Local scope for a particular network
> technology should be published in an RFC.  For example, such a scope
> definition would be appropriate for publication in an "IPv6-over-foo"
> RFC.
>
> Any RFCs that include the definition of a Realm-Local scope will be
> added to the IANA "IPv6 Multicast Address Scopes" registry under the
> Realm-Local scope entry, and those specifications must include such a
> request in their IANA Considerations.
>
> Section 5 of this document gives the definition of scop 3 for IEEE
> 802.15.4 [IEEE802.15.4] networks.
>
> 4. Definition of Automatic and Administratively Configured Scopes (Updates RFC 4007)
>
> Section 5 of RFC 4007 [RFC4007] and Section 2.7 of RFC 4291 [RFC4291]
> disagree on the way in which multicast scop 3 is configured.  To
> resolve that disagreement, the last bullet in the list in Section 5 of
> [RFC4007] is updated as follows:
>
> OLD:
>
> o  The boundaries of zones of a scope other than interface-local,
> link-local, and global must be defined and configured by network
> administrators.
>
> NEW:
>
> o  The boundaries of zones of a scope are defined by the IPv6
> addressing architecture [RFC4291] and updated by RFC 7346.
>
> 5. Definition of Realm-Local Scope for IEEE 802.15.4
>
> When used in an IP-over-IEEE802.15.4 network, scop 3 is defined to
> include all interfaces sharing a Personal Area Network Identifier (PAN
> ID).